# About Hardware devices

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask about recommendation about hardware devices? (Health related devices). Like devices that measure Blood pressure etc.
I asked that [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135777/health-device-which-allow-to-access-their-data-through-api-calls) but I think it was not right place

Comment: Related question on Meta Stack Overflow: [Stack Exchange and hardware questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270703)

Comment: As far as I know, there are no "make me a shopping list of <these things>" sites on [se]. All answers to such questions would be opinion-based, and links tend to become unavailable over time. There are tons of shopping related sites that do reviews of different things, but (thankfully) none of them are here at [se].

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware there aren't any Stack Exchange sites that specifically accept hardware recommendations at the moment. One problem as per the close message is they become quickly obsolete but it might be worth a try in EE chatroom. While it's a fairly quiet room such questions are welcome and at least one semi-regular I can think of is involved with medical devices.

I've never used the site but there is also the [Physical Fitness Beta](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) site. For this specific question it might be worth asking in their chat or on their meta if the question or some variant of it would be OK.

Another thing that I've heard of but never used is the USB PHDC (personal healthcare device class) class. Maybe if you did a bit of research into that and found some suitable devices based on that standard you could narrow the question down a bit to just interfacing with one and transporting the data elsewhere, although that might remain a bit broad depending on how far you got.