# Where can I ask questions about which laptop to purchase?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about which laptop to purchase?

I need help to choose between two laptop brands; is there a Stack Exchange site for these type of questions?

Comment: related: [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/201151) , 
[Where can I ask questions regarding mobile hardware?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239236/201151) , [About Hardware devices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242556/201151)

Comment: The answer is nowhere. There is an [are51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) but that is just past 50% commitment...

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)